# Unit Testing MVC3 Client-Side functionality

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, dom

I'm having a hard time grasping the methods I see used to unit test UI functionality for a website (in this case, using ASP.NET MVC3).  I tried using Watin, which, in a general sense what I want, with the exception of having to rely an actual instance of a web browser in order to make it work, as it complicates the whole process quite a bit, especially with CI.

In my ideal world this is how I imagine a test working:

1. Pass a model to a view, get the output
2. Populate a programmatic DOM with the view output
3. The test would trigger DOM events to simulate clicking a button, for example, and verify that the DOM was manipulated in the expected way.

I realize this would require both a javascript engine and a DOM implementation either written in .NET or with .NET bindings. Does an obvious solution to my problem exist?  If not, is there anything particularly dumb/wrong about the way I'd like to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is known as a headless browser - [XBrowser](http://xbrowser.codeplex.com/) is one such effort, though the last check-in dates from April 2010.

Also see [this post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/) on using HtmlUnit in .NET development.

Comment: I think you got me pointed in the right direction.  I'm looking at phantomJS now to see if it's I could reasonably integrate.

Comment: @w.brian - Knowing what to search for is half the job these days ;)

Comment: Ain't that the truth!  I'm really surprised a .NET solution doesn't already exist considering how insanely useful it would be.  Perhaps I will look into cloning XBrowser and attempt to get it working.